# Substitute all occurrences of n spaces with a single character

Tags: sed

I would like to use sed (is this the best tool?) to go from this:

```
foo     bar    buzz     fuzz
```

to this:

```
foo|bar|buzz|fuzz
```

How can this be done ?

Many thanks :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ sed 's/\s\s*/|/g' < input
```

Comment: The `\s` shorthand is not POSIX-compliant, and may not work across all versions of sed. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have 5 spaces between your items and they are in a file called test.txt:

```
sed -i "s/     /|/g" test
```

Answer (score 1):

### Use the [:SPACE:] POSIX Class

If the number of spaces could change, or might be a mix of spaces and tabs, then you want to use a POSIX class to replace a series of whitespace characters with a single pipe symbol globally within the current pattern space. For example:

```
$ echo 'foo     bar    buzz     fuzz' | sed 's/[[:space:]]\+/|/g'
foo|bar|buzz|fuzz
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU sed:

```
sed -r 's/ +/|/g'
```